# Storing 100+ sentences on iOS?

Tags: ios, storage

I'm looking for a way to store over 100+ sentences for a studying tool.  What way would be the most efficient to do so?

Comment: use a `plist` file, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only storing on the order of 100 - 1000 sentences, efficiency (in terms of runtime and memory usage) is irrelevant. In english, the average number of characters in a sentence is approximately 100.

Assuming that you use UTF-32 encoding, the storage of 1000 sentences will only take 4 * 100 * 1000 bytes (~400 kilobytes). Even the original iPhones an iPod touches had 128MB of RAM. You will only be updating this in response to user input, so memory speed is also not going to be a performance issue.

Just store the strings in a simple and natural way. You are more likely to have performance issues in the rendering of graphical interface than in the storage of the text for the underlying logic.